# Catch 22: when an openID fails

Tags: support, bug, login, openid

I opened this account because I cannot access my email address at my usual account.

I wrote 3 times to 'contact us' asking to merge the 2 accounts, changing the old address with the new one, and then maybe delete this one.

Probably these requests are dealt with by machine, and I keep receiving a request to confirm which is sent to both addresses, But of course I cannot click the link sent to the failed address.

What can I do?

Comment: I've also tagged this as a bug 'cause if this is what the system is doing it's clearly not achieving its aims.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're looking at this. In the meantime, use 'other' as the reason on the contact form, point to this meta post and give us links to both of your profiles - we'll take care of the merge manually.

(This is also standing guidance as to what to do if you're stuck in this while we work out a way to break out of the robot loop).

An interim solution would be to simply include a link in the emails we send that says "If you can't complete this process, contact us directly using this link and give us the following details" - which is probably the only way to do it since verification of some kind is needed.

I *thought* we had something like that included, anyway, we'll take a look at it.